# Velocity problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The time it takes to an object $\text A$ to travel $72$ km is greater by $2$ hours, than the time it takes to body $\text B$ to travel $8$ km. It is known that the velocity of body $\text A$ is greater by $m$ km/h more than that of body $\text B$. ($m\gt0$) . Find the velocity of body $B$ (expressed in $m$).

I tried to solve this, reaching that eventually t1,2  is the result of some quadratic equation with plenty of unknowns, so I got stuck there...any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ be the velocity of $B$ (so that the velocity of $A$ is $v+m$). Recall that velocity is displacement over time, so time is displacement over velocity. This yields:
\begin{align*}
\frac{72}{v+m} &= 2 + \frac{8}{v} \\
72(v) &= 2(v)(v+m) + 8(v+m) \\
36v &= v(v+m) + 4(v+m) \\
36v &= v^2+mv + 4v+4m \\
0 &= v^2+(m-32)v + (4m) \\
v &= \frac{-(m-32)\pm\sqrt{(m-32)^2-4(1)(4m)}}{2(1)} \\
v &= \frac{32-m\pm\sqrt{(m-32)^2-16m}}{2} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Nailed it, so to speak..

Answer (score 1):

You have two equations there and you know velocity is $distance\over time$:

$${72\over v_a }{=}{8\over v_b }+ 2$$
$$v_a = v_b +m$$

Sub in equation 2 into 1 for $v_a$ and you get:

$${72 \over {v_b+m}} = {8\over v_b}+2$$

solve for $v_b$ and you are there.

Comment: I got there, but it's not that simple...have you got to the final solution?

Comment: Just as a check http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+72%2F%28v%2Bm%29%3D2%2B8%2Fv+for+v&x=-733&y=-138